# JS for loop not working correctly, trying to loop through an array of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to code the dice game Yahtzee in Javascript for fun.  I have a basic interface set up with images of dice.  In reference to my problem, a few Yahtzee rules to know would be:

There are 5 dice

After 3 rolls, the player has to pick a points category to score with

Here is the code that is not working:

```
var die1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1),
die2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1),
die3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1),
die4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1),
die5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1),
dieArray = ["", die1, die2, die3, die4, die5],
optionResult1 = 0;

document.getElementById("option1").onclick =  function() {
if (rollCount == 3 & option1 == false) {
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        i++;
        if (dieArray[i] == 1) {
            optionResult1++;
        }
        if (i = 5) {
            option1 = true;
            document.getElementById("optionResult1").innerHTML = optionResult1;
            console.log("finished");
        }
    }
            console.log(optionResult1);
} else if (rollCount != 3) {
    document.getElementById("dialogue").innerHTML = "You cannot pick this yet because you have not rolled 3 times.";
} else if (option1 == true) {
    document.getElementById("dialogue").innerHTML = "You cannot pick this because you have already used this category.";
}
}
```

What should happen (assuming it's the third roll and this points category has not already been chosen previously):

The for loop should go through the dieArray and for each die that is a "one", add 1 to the optionResult1 variable.  If there were three "ones" out of five dice, optionResult1 should be "3", etc.

What instead happens is that it usually comes back as 1 less than what it should be.  Even if I can see in the console that the array clearly shows three "ones", it will give me "2", or sometimes "0".  Is there anything wrong with the code you see?  There is obviously other code in the document, but I am fairly certain the problem is within this function.  Sorry if this was confusing, it's probably easier to understand if you have played Yahtzee...

I know that I could do the same thing with 5 if statements instead, but I am trying to learn from this and I am fairly confident this SHOULD work, I must just be doing something wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: `if (i = 5) {` should be `if (i === 5) {`   ... and `for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {` should be `for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {`

Comment: Why do you increment `i` twice? Why do you have an empty string as element zero in the die array?

Comment: Yep as @DustinHoffner said you need to make sure you're using `==` or even better using `===`

Comment: Fire up your developer tools and tell us what errors you're getting.

Comment: I've changed the code as @DustinHoffner recommended, and removed the i++ in the loop (I have no idea why I did that, not thinking straight...).  Now, I seem to get the right value for optionResult1, but the code inside the "i == 5" statement doesn't seem to be triggering at all...which is the part that is supposed to display the score and make the point category "turn off".  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: A lot of mistakes there. Ten minutes in and it's still not working. Half the variables you use are undefined.

Comment: @Andrew no errors.  Everything looks fine that is showing up, except that I am not seeing the "finished" console log that I put to verify the code was working properly.

Comment: Your variable `i` never becomes 5 because you loop as long as i smaller than 5 `i<5`

Comment: @tobsta they are not undefined, I just didn't use them in this part of the code and didn't feel the need to put in anything that wasn't directly relevant.  They do all have values.

Comment: I adjusted the code for the second if statement to (i == 4) and removed my blank array value, and everything works as it should.  I really appreciate the help guys, I know I made a lot of really dumb mistakes but hopefully now I won't make them again!